# Using TikZ absolute coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I wonder is that possible to use absolute coordinates regarding all document?
Please see my example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[red]
(30pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue]
(3pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why red and blue lines have the same left x-coordinate? I would like to move the second on 27pt left!

Comment: Try putting both drawings in one `begin{tikzpicture} ... end{tikzpicture}` environment.

Comment: In that case the second line will be drawn over the first.

Comment: It seems that you only want the `x` coordinate to be absolute, but the `y` coordinate to be relative.  Is that right?

Comment: Actually not. I have mentioned *x* as example I would like to have relative (x,y)-coordinates.

Comment: You said "absolute" in the question, but in the comment you said "relative".  If "relative" is correct, then the key question is "relative to *what*?".

Comment: Heh :) Sorry for misunderstanding! Yes I want absolute coordinates, i.e. mean relative to ALL document's origin point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To automatically make all `tikzpicture`s align on the origin, you can set `\tikzset{every picture/.append style={trim left=0}}`. This sets the left margin to be at the `x` position of the origin. Note that you will run into trouble if you use negative coordinates, since these will protrude out of the image. In that case, you'd have to set `trim left` to a negative value that is large enough to include all points.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={trim left=0}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[red]
(30pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[blue]
(3pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about *y*-coordinate? Can I use similar approach?

Comment: Do you want to overlay the pictures, so that the point `(0,0)` is the same point on the page, even if you use them in different `tikzpicture`s, or do you want the y positions of two tikzpictures that are next to each other to be the same?

Comment: I want the first.

Comment: Why don't you want to put both drawings into the same `tikzpicture`?

Comment: Because the second drawing is NOT TikZ drawing. I have one TikZ figure and one figure composed with *\qbezier* s. I want to depict them together, overlapping each other!

Comment: Oh, that's quite an important information! May I suggest you edit your question to include that, with a minimal example? That's very different from a pure TikZ problem

Comment: I have created the new one question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43988/using-tikz-along-with-picture-environment

Answer (score 4):

The answer is suggested by `percusse`. Each `tikzpicture` is typeset in its own box. The box is made as small as possible to typeset all what's in it. For example, a `tikzpicture` consisting of a square with lower left position (1,1) and 
upper right position (2,2) will still have a width of 1cm and a hight of 1cm.

The coordinates in your `tikzpicture`s are completely relative to their own `tikzpicture`s. This explains why you cannot relate the coordinates in one `tikzpicture` to those of another `tikzpicture` (unless you're using `remember pictures`).

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation! But is that possible to use to TikZ coordinates in the same coord system as native LaTeX use? I mean here when I put (1,2) point in TikZ environment it will be put in the same place where     *\begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(1,2){Point}
    \end{picture}* will be put.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean with _the_ same coordinate system. TikZ has several coordinate systems. One of the most popular notations for specifying coordinates is`(<x>,<y>)`, which is the implicit notation for the `canvas coordinate system`. LaTeX `picture` coordinates are expressed in multiples of the length variable `\unitlength`, which defaults to `1pt`. Perhaps if you can explain why you want to use the same coordinate systems we can see if there's a solution.

Comment: I tried to rephrase my previous comment but the system didn't let me. If you redefine `\unitlength` to `1cm` (`\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}`) you can specify coodinates in a similar way as in the TikZ `canvas coordinate system`.

Comment: I am afraid me point you to the wrong way. We don't talk about *units* here. I just want to use TikZ primitives in the LaTeX canvas's coord system. I think that other responders have given the solution already...

Comment: @MichaelZ No worries. Glad your problem's solved.

Answer (score 4):

In normal TeX there is a `\phantom` that is often used to leave the same amount of space as required by its arguments.  You could do something similar by adding a `\path (0pt,0pt)` for both pictures.  This ensures that the left hand side starts at the same `x`-coordinate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0pt,0pt);
    \draw[red] (30pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0pt,0pt);
    \draw[blue] (3pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn’t it possible to automate adding an orgin with the `every picture` style?

Comment: @Tobi: Good idea. Looks like Jake already posted that as an answer.  But not sure you'd want to do that to _every_ picture.

Comment: I don’t but the OP may want this ;-) Otherwise it should be easy to create a `set orgin` style with `trim left=0` as @Jake posted.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the most simple solution that can be applied to the each particular picture!

Answer (score 3):

Add a origine with a node

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(O) at (0,0){};
    \coordinate(O) at (0,0);
    \filldraw[red]
    (30pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node(O) at (0,0){};
    \filldraw[blue]
    (3pt, 9pt) -- (130pt, 9pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```